# Sieve - Login with crypted password

Tags: php, email, authentication, sha512, dovecot

I am creating webpanel for managing email accounts, aliases etc 
and wondering how to get "Set vacation" to work.

We are using Dovecot as IMAP-server and Pidgeonhole.

Library that i have checked https://github.com/loconox/ needs

```
        $sieved = new \LibSieve\ManageSieve(MANAGESIEVE_HOST, 4190, MANAGESIEVE_USER, MANAGESIEVE_PASS);
        $sieved->sieve_login();
```

Dovecot uses sha512-crypt password schema, so how i can use that library without knowing plain password.

This panel what i am creating, is allowing to admin enable/disable vacation messages for someone.

Answer (score 0):

To force `vacation` you do not need to manipulate user's sieve rules. There is four sieve rulesets groups checked/proceeded on every incoming message:

- global sieve
- sieve_before*
- user's own sieve or default one if there is no user's sieve
- sieve_after*

You can place the vacation code into the global/before sieve without knowledge about user's login/pass and it's possible to prevent execution of the any other sieve after `vacation` code.

Refer to the dovecot's wiki for further reading: https://wiki.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Configuration

Answer (score 0):

Yes but user can set up vacation message from Roundcube webmail and our management panel. Both ways should edit same data. How this can be done without shell-scripting?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use master-password login from select sources to bypass knowing user's password.

```
passdb {
  driver = static
  # you can also put an encrypted password here
  args = password=verysecretpassword allow_nets=trusted/net
}
```

NB, you need to put this in correct place in your passdb. You can also put this inside protocol sieve { }